# How Kafka reply works in case of log compaction?

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka if log compaction is enabled it will store only recent key values. If we try to reply these messages, will it just replay latest messages? How exactly Kafka-reply works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Offsets of earlier, duplicate keys are dropped and the newest key offset is kept. The consumer skips over gaps in the broker offsets to read all messages available

Also, log compaction happens on a schedule, so you might see the same key within a partition for a certain amount of time, depending on the the properties defined on the broker/topic.